# display number of records of total records using php pagination

Tags: php

I am working on a custom php pagination. everything works well and displays the records, i am trying to code .. showing X to X of X records .. but is facing some issues. any suggestions.

current code.

```
 $total = 18 <- get the number of records with sql query.
 $limit = 15; <- number of records to display on a page
 $page_no = $current_page <- gets the page # from the url using smarty. 

// Showing from

$from = (($page_no * $limit) - $limit + 1); <- gives the starting record - (working)

// showing to

$to = ($page_no * $limit); <- of course it will work for page one but page 2 will display 
                           30. i know this is wrong but here is where i am stuck. i did 
                           some other coding but have problems there too. 

output is something like this.

Showing $from to $to of $total records

Page one i get: Showing 1 to 15 of 18 records

Page two i get: Showing 16 to 30 of 18 records
```

Any idea how to get this working properly?

Comment: `$to = min( ($page_no * $limit), $total )`

Answer (score 0):

$to = min( ($page_no * $limit), $total )

Works great. Thanks Waxen

Answer (score 0):

You could set $to to something like following.

> $to = ($total - $page_no * $limit > 0 ? $page_no * $limit : $total);